# Send a Map (internally converted to XML) to a Web Service

Tags: xml, web-services, dictionary

I have a Map in Java and I want to send it to a Web Service. The Web Service expects an XML.

Example

```
Map<String, String> dummyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

dummyMap.put("A", "a");
dummyMap.put("B", "b");
dummyMap.put("C", "c");
dummyMap.put("D", "d");
```

Is there a tool where I can send this Map that will be internally converted to an XML and sent to the Web Service in Java?

Comment: Please try to add more information to your question. What kind of Map? What language are you using? What have you tried so far? As it is now, this question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: Hi Mata, I have edited the question with some specifics. I have not tried anything because I am not aware of any tool. I have been doing it manually all these days which I want to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ... I am using your map .... Fill in the rest of the details where I have set comments ....

The connection will be POST by default ...

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import cjm.component.mb.commons.MBConstants;
import cjm.component.mb.ws.WSMessenger;

public class TestClass
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Map<String, String> dummyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        dummyMap.put("A", "a");
        dummyMap.put("B", "b");
        dummyMap.put("C", "c");
        dummyMap.put("D", "d");

        WSMessenger wsMessenger = new WSMessenger();

        String communicationURL = "http://whatever"; //Web Service Host URL

        Map<String, String> propertyMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); // add all the properties related to the Web Service (like Hostname, Content Map, etc.) to this map

        Map<String, Object> responseMap = wsMessenger.sendRequest(dummyMap, communicationURL , propertyMap );

        System.out.println(responseMap.get(MBConstants.STATUS)); //Web Service hit Status Code
        System.out.println(responseMap.get(MBConstants.RESPONSE_XML)); //Web Service Response as an XML
        System.out.println(responseMap.get(MBConstants.RESPONSE)); //Web Service Response as a Map
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: cjm.component.mb? Whats that?

Comment: Messenger Box (http://capsulesforthejavamind.blogspot.in/2015/02/messenger-box_4.html)

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question and is not an informative answer. SO should have both correct *and* informative answers.